# How to add webPart to Page with PowerShell from WebPart Gallery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, 2016, visual-web-part, publishing-page

I want to get my Custom WebPart by name and add into a Page with PowerShell from (*Web part gallery*):

> --> Edit Page --> Insert --> Web Part --> Custom

WebParts in image are added from Custom Feature(.wsp package) generated by Visual Studio

```
function AddWebPartsSolution($webAppURL){
    $userSolutionFileName = $Infrastructure.WebApplication.UserSolutionFile
    Add-SPSolution $scriptBase\Solution\$userSolutionFileName
    Install-SPSolution –Identity $userSolutionFileName –WebApplication $webAppURL –GACDeployment
}


function EnableWebPartsFeature($siteCollectionURL){
    #Get all Features -->  Get-SPFeature | Sort -Property DisplayName
    $featureName = $Infrastructure.WebApplication.UserSolutionName
    Enable-SPFeature -Identity featureName -Url $siteCollectionURL
}
```

**Image:**

[image]

I read [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasham/sharepoint-adding-web-part-on-pages-using-powershell-script/) example, but PowerShell script get web part from local system. I need to get web part from image.

Where is the folder of Webparts from WebPart Gallery?

How to do this?

Comment: So for example, you want to add the calendar webpart to page ?

Comment: Custom web parts, seen my updated question. WebParts in image are from my Custom Feature generated by Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and modify the below PS script:

```
#ensure that you use the site collection root url 
#if you use subsite url, will throw error since webpart gallery 
#exists only in the site collection root site

$web = Get-SPWeb "https://site-collection-url"

$pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)

$publishingPage = $pubWeb.GetPublishingPage("https://site-collection-url/Pages/Test.aspx");

$publishingPage.CheckOut();

$list = $web.Lists["Web Part Gallery"]   

#use the webpart title or the .webpart file name

$wpl = $list.Items | where {$_.Title -eq "Your Webpart Name"}   

$xmlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($wpl.File.OpenBinaryStream());   

$errorMsg = ""   

$wpManager = $publishingPage.ListItem.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);

$webPart = $wpManager.ImportWebPart($xmlReader, [ref]$errorMsg)   

#insert webpart into header zone at index 1

$wpManager.AddWebPart($webpart,"Header",1)  

$publishingPage.CheckIn("Added webpart");

$publishingPage.ListItem.File.Publish("Published");

$wpManager.Dispose()

$web.Dispose()
```

Modified from:

[Web Parts Connections via powershell](http://troyvssharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/08/web-parts-connections-via-powershell.html)

[Add webpart to publishing page using PS](http://sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Add-WebPart-to-the-Publishing-Page-using-PowerShell-in-SharePoint-2013)

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Microsoft PNP PowerShell Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/pnp-powershell-overview), you can add WebParts to pages pretty easily.

For example to add from a webpart file:

```
Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "/sites/demo/sitepages/home.aspx" -Path "c:\myfiles\listview.webpart" -ZoneId "Header" -ZoneIndex 1
```

Or to add from XML where $webpart represents the XML:

```
Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "/sites/demo/sitepages/home.aspx" -XML $webpart -ZoneId "Header" -ZoneIndex 1
```

Adding to a wiki page has its own cmdlets but also can be added via path or XML:

```
Add-PnPWebPartToWikiPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "/sites/demo/sitepages/home.aspx" -XML $webpart -Row 1 -Column 1
```

The site in the link above has examples on how to connect using the PNP library and how to get the WebPartXML if you need it.  Good luck!

Comment: I want to get webpart form Webpart gallery by name and add into a page.