# How to get webPart XML with powershell from SharePoint WebPart Gallery

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, powershell, visual-web-part, xml

I want to get web part XML from SharePoint Web Parts Gallery(not locally) for add webpart into a List page.

**This is my code:**

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb $webURL
$spSiteCollection = Get-SPWeb -Identity $spWeb.Site.Url

$pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($spSiteCollection)
$pageName = "$pageName.aspx"
$list = $spWeb.Lists[$listName]
$publishingPage = $list.RootFolder.Files | where {$_.Name -eq $pageName}
$publishingPage.CheckOut();

$webPartslist = $spSiteCollection.Lists["Web Part Gallery"]   

#use the webpart title or the .webpart file name

$wpl = $webPartslist.Items | where {$_.Title -eq $webPartName}   

$webPartFile = spWeb.GetFile($wpl.Url)

$xmlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($webPartFile.OpenBinaryStream());   

$errorMsg = ""   

$wpManager = $publishingPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
```

**Result is:**

[image]

Comment: Modify this line as `$webPartFile = $spWeb.GetFile($wpl.File)` and check

Comment: Sorry modified comment, it should be `$webPartFile = $spWeb.GetFile($wpl.File)` , missed adding the `$`

Comment: Seen my updated question

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233319/how-to-add-webpart-to-page-with-powershell-from-webpart-gallery/233329#233329

Result from this accepted answer is the same.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand. The error is gone, right ? What's the issue ? not able to add webpart ?

Comment: I want to get xml of file FundGHGEditForm.webpart and pass to = $wpManager.ImportWebPart($xmlReader, [ref]$errorMsg)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71401/discussion-between-goshky-and-gautam-sheth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add Web Part from SharePoint WebPart Gallery to publishing page, the following PowerShell for your reference.

```
$webURL="http://sp2013/sites/team"
$listName="Pages"
$pageName="Home"
$webPartName="SharePointProject1 - VisualWebPart1"

$spWeb = Get-SPWeb $webURL
$spSiteCollection = Get-SPWeb -Identity $spWeb.Site.Url

$pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($spSiteCollection)
$pageName = "$pageName.aspx"

$list = $spWeb.Lists[$listName]
$publishingPage = $list.RootFolder.Files | where {$_.Name -eq $pageName}

$spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true

if($publishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckedOutByUser -eq $null)
{           
     # Though it is newly created or already there, checkout.
     $publishingPage.CheckOut()
}

$webPartGallery = $spSiteCollection.Lists["Web Part Gallery"]   

#use the webpart title or the .webpart file name
$webpart=$webPartGallery.Items | ? { $_.Title -eq $webPartName}

if($webpart -eq $null) {
    Write-Host("Unable to retrieve webpart: $fileName") -ForegroundColor Red
}
else {  
    Write-Host("----------Adding Webpart--------")-ForegroundColor Yellow
    $webpartmanager=$publishingPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
    $errorMsg = "";
    $xmlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($webpart.File.OpenBinaryStream());
    $webpart = $webpartmanager.ImportWebPart($xmlReader,[ref]"Error")    
    $webpartmanager.AddWebPart($webpart, "zone1", 1);
    Write-Host("Webpart is added successfully") -ForegroundColor Green ;
}
# Check in the Page with Comments
$publishingPage.CheckIn("Added webpart")
# Publish the Page With Comments
$publishingPage.Publish("Publish")
$spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false
```

**More information**: http://sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Add-AppParts-to-Publishing-Pages-in-SharePoint-2013-using-PowerShell